# Recommendation on how to create a dynamic web app using asp.net and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am wondering how to proceed on a project where I have to create an UI that shows kendo grids based on a selected ProductionLine.  I want to create a dropdown in the nav bar on top that selects a ProductionLine and is persistent across pages but I am unsure how to do this.

I am currently working on having all the kendo be able to filter by foreign key ProductionLines but I want to go a step further and transfer between different views without having to refilter.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in the _layout page?

Comment: One way we do it is to add a session variable "CurrentProductLine". May want to add an action filter that checks for existence as well.